# How do I convert a render array to plain HTML?

Tags: 7, ajax

I have a render array with a list of items.

```
$array = array(
  'list' => array(
    '#items' => $items,
    '#theme' => 'item_list'
  )
);
```

I tried to use it with `ajax_command_html()`, which works perfectly with a simple HTML string, but it doesn't work when it gets a render array.

Can I somehow convert this render array to an HTML string to use it with that function?

Comment: Did you try [drupal_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7.x)?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Didn't expected this to be so easy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ajax_prepare_response()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_prepare_response/7.x) contains the following code.

```
$html = is_string($page_callback_result) ? $page_callback_result : drupal_render($page_callback_result);
$commands[] = ajax_command_insert(NULL, $html);
// Add the status messages inside the new content's wrapper element, so that
// on subsequent Ajax requests, it is treated as old content.
$commands[] = ajax_command_prepend(NULL, theme('status_messages'));
```

So, to achieve the same (i.e. convert a render array into a HTML string), you can call [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7.x) passing the render array to the function.

```
 $render_array = array(
    '#items' => $items,
    '#theme' => 'item_list'
 );

 return ajax_command_html($elector, drupal_render($render_array));
```

Also `theme()` would return a HTML string, and you could as well use the following code.

```
 return ajax_command_html($elector, theme('item_list', array('items' => $items)));
```

Since Drupal 8 doesn't have the `theme()` function anymore, I would use `drupal_render()` just to make easier to convert Drupal 7 code to Drupal 8.

Keep in mind that `drupal_render()` is expecting an array; in the case you are calling it from a function that could receive a string as argument, you need to verify you are passing an array to `drupal_render()`, as the code I shown does.

Comment: I added example code for both the functions I suggest to use.